# Getting and updateing related values in aAngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a AnuglarJS app. The app is hooked up to a Web Api service, from where i get all the data.

I have the following scenario; the user can create and edit a car model.
The car model, consist of;

```
* int Id
* string Name
* DateTime date
* ManufactureId
```

manufacture model consist of;

```
* int Id
* string Name
```

The first 3 is easy enough to create and edit via AngularJS. Via DTO's i can map it, so i get the manufacture name.

But how/what is best practice, when i want to create/edit the model, when we know there is a relation to another table/model, in this example the manufacture?

Currently i have a form in Angular, like so;

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.car.name">
<input type="date" ng-model="ctrl.car.date">
<select ng-model="ctrl.car.name">
    <option value="x">manufacture</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" ng-click="ctrl.save()">Save</button>
```

In the controller i have this;

```
vm.save = function() {
            vm.car.$save(
                function(data) {
                    vm.message = "... Save Complete";
                },
                function(response) {
                    vm.message = response.statusText + "\r\n";
                    if (response.data.modelState) {
                        for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
                            vm.message += response.data.modelState[key] + "\r\n";
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.data.exceptionMessage)
                        vm.message += response.data.exceptionMessage;
                });
        };
```

and the car factory looks like this;

```
myApp.factory('Car', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://api.com/api/cars/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    });
```

So i guess my questions is;

1) The above code works fine, as long as we are handling simple datatypes (name, date etc.). But how would one handle the Manufacture property?

2) How could i, in a nice fashion, get all the current Manufacture, and populate my dropdown with this data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you know the property name you can call them by name other wise either use
 for each for key, value or use data[i]

Please let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Comment: My main consern is how, would i, in my controller, set the dropdown to take data from one api source (manufacture) and keep the rest using the car api? What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to bind the data from two sources? if yes, create array with the structure you wanted to use and push data from all the sources in to that array. Bind this constructed with your dropdown. Let me if it make sense.

Comment: Yes, 2 sources. I have the mnufacture from one APi and the car info from another API. Could you give a simple example of what you are saying?

Comment: Updating my answer since it contains some sample code

Comment: I guess you are looking for master-child data. You wanted to list the car information of selected manufacturer? Please clarify.